# Chrome Extension AJAX always caches errors

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on updating an old Chrome Extension I have. It works fine if the user is already logged into Google (It's a wrapper on Google Tasks) but if the user isn't logged into Google it caches the 404 response on the AJAX and will never, for any reason, refresh it after the user logs in. Currently the only only way to make it work is to manually go to the page (just type it in the address bar) the AJAX call is trying to retrieve after which all will work fine. Reloading the extension and opening/closing Chrome will not reset it.

On the flip side, if the user begins the session logged in all is fine. When they log out the badge resets as it should but it will never reset once they log back in.

I've tried cache: false, I've tried appending a random variable to the URL. I've tried xmlHTTPRequest.abort() and everything else I can think of with no luck.

Here's the code:

https://github.com/Bit51/Better-Google-Tasks/blob/master/Src/js/utilities.js

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was due to the use of "Background Scripts" instead of "Background Page." Switching to the latter allowed me to be able to reset the call.